# Fill CSV to make data continuous

Tags: excel, csv

I have a CSV file in a spreadsheet but the data is not continuous.

**My current sheet:**

```
ID1 / Info1 / Info2 / Sinfo1

ID1 / (Blank) / (Blank) / Sinfo2

ID1 / (Blank) / (Blank) / Sinfo3

ID1 / (Blank) / (Blank) / Sinfo4
```

**What I need:**

```
ID2 / Info1 / Info2 / Sinfo1

ID2 / Info1 / Info2 / Sinfo2

ID2 / Info1 / Info2 / Sinfo3

ID2 / Info1 / Info2 / Sinfo4
```

The objective is to work with a Pivot Table, and when certain cells are blank, I just can't analyze it.

Does anybody know a way to do this in a efficient way?
Not really practical to do it w/ CTRL + D, I have a few thousand lines.

Thanks a lot.